# Author.php Page views counter

Tags: author, count, views

Wondering if some one can help me.

Im looking for a page counter for the author.php

Ive got about 300 authors on the site and they would like a counter to show them how many times there "profiles" (author.php) is being viewed.

Ive looked for plugins, but cant find one that does the author.php
I assumed I needed to create a field in the user meta for the counter record. I created a "single line" field type and a "number" type field but cant seem to get it to work. The code I came up with was

```
add_action('wp', function() {

if( is_author() ) {

global $authordata;

$user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$meta = get_user_meta( $curauth->ID, 'wcpf-count', TRUE );
$meta = '' !== $meta ? explode( ',', $meta ) : array();
$meta = array_filter( array_unique( $meta ) );

if( ! in_array( $user_ip, $meta ) ) {

array_push( $meta, $user_ip );
update_user_meta( $curauth->ID, 'wcpf-count', '1' );

} } });
```

and then placed this in the author.php because curauth is being called to get the author data. However this did not work at all.

Can any body assist please

Comment: You should never use post meta to store views, it's incredibly unreliable due to race conditions, and involves DB writes on the frontend. You need to use a 3rd party service or software to track the views, as there are special data storage concerns necessary to store data reliably

Comment: Also this page is impossible to cache if you want to do this, the speed of your page loads will be significantly impacted as a result

Comment: Ok Thanks. I will look and see what plugins/software I can find